# Get value of date-picker jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
 var dateFrom = $('#date-frm').datepicker('getDate');
 alert(dateFrom);
```

It displays:
`Thu May 09 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0800`

I want to display it in this format:
2013-05-09

Comment: `getDate()` returns a Javascript Date object, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the format of datepicker like

```
var dateFrom = $('#date-frm').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
```

you can have look at this [article](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-UI-Changing-the-date-format-for-Datepicker-P1023.html) or datepicker [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

[getDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) returns Date object not a string, you can format the date object using [formatDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)

```
var dateFrom = $('#date-frm').datepicker('getDate');
alert($.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', dateFrom));
```